# Redirect htaccess issue with pdf?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This is all of the `.htaccess` code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset Off

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

Redirect 301 /content http://www.axelen.ro/tapet/
Redirect 301 /content/documents/xh76.pdf http://www.axelen.ro/
```

So for some reason it does not redirect PDFs. It redirects me to 404. If you try http://www.axelen.ro/content it will successfully redirects to http://www.axelen.ro/tapet/,  but the PDF is not working, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The redirect for your `xh76.pdf` is not working because the first generic redirect rule (`/content`) matches the request URL -> it's applied first.

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect:

> Then any request beginning with URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Redirect /service http://foo2.example.com/service
> ```
>
> If the client requests http://example.com/service/foo.txt, it will be told to access http://foo2.example.com/service/foo.txt instead. Only complete path segments are matched, so the above example would not match a request for http://example.com/servicefoo.txt.

The solution could be to swap the two rules so the more specific rule is being tested first or use a regular expression (eg. `/content$`) and the [`RedirectMatch` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) as the documentation says.

Comment: If I remove the Redirect 301 /content http://www.axelen.ro/tapet/ and try the url with the pdf I get the same result

Comment: I tried in this order : Redirect 301 /content/documents/xh76.pdf http://www.axelen.ro/
Redirect 301 /content http://www.axelen.ro/tapet/ , but i got the same result

Comment: @Chester From my point of view it's currently working (redirecting to the root of the domain). Have you tried using a dummy tool like `curl` to see the actual HTTP response? Your browser (whatever that is) can be caching 301 from its principle (301 = Moved permanently).

Comment: Actually I can see that the 1st rule is not being applied. I don't know why, but I'd try using the `RedirectMatch` as described earlier.